# Editing text file in command line and make a new file

Tags: bash

I have a big file look like the example:

```
chr1:16872433-16872504  54  112622
chr1:16872433-16872504  55  112110
chr1:16872433-16872504  56  110996
chr1:16872433-16872504  57  110306
chr1:16861773-16861845  20  38808
chr1:16861773-16861845  21  39768
chr1:16861773-16861845  22  40344
chr1:16861773-16861845  23  40637
chr1:16861773-16861845  24  41311
chr2:7990338-7990408    8   0
chr2:7990338-7990408    9   0
chr2:7990338-7990408    10  0
chr2:7990338-7990408    11  0
chr2:7990338-7990408    12  0
```

I want to extract every part starting with "`chr1:16872433-16872504`" and make a new `.txt` file.
how can I do that in bash? I tried `grep` command but I do not know how to make it conditional.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E 'chr1:16872433-16872504' your.txt  > new.txt
```

gives you the following output

```
chr1:16872433-16872504  54  112622

chr1:16872433-16872504  55  112110

chr1:16872433-16872504  56  110996

chr1:16872433-16872504  57  110306
```

as per your requirement ["chr1:16872433-16872504"]

Comment: There is no need to use cat, and add "bets and braces" to the solution with regular expressions checking that the text is at the start of the line. grep -E '$chr1:16872433-16872504' your.txt > new.txt

Comment: I tried both 1- grep -E 'chr1:16872433-16872504' your.txt  > new.txt and 2- grep -E '$chr1:16872433-16872504' your.txt > new.txt but the new.txt is empty

Comment: check the output , before inserting into new.txt
Use grep -E 'chr1:16872433-16872504' your.txt